# Intuition behind risk-return realation (Mark Joshi's concepts 1.2)

Tags: risk, intuition

In Mark Joshi's "The concepts and practice of mathematical finance" section 1.2, it is given an intuitive motivation behind "high risk high returns" claim. It goes as follows:

*Given that all assets are correctly priced by the market, how can we distinguish
one from another? Part of the information the market has about an asset is its riskiness.
Thus the riskiness is already included in the price, and since it will reduce the
price, the value of the asset without taking into account its riskiness must be higher
than that of a less risky asset. This means that in a year from now we can expect
the risky asset to be worth more than the less risky one. So increased riskiness
means greater returns, but only on average - it also means a greater chance of
losing money.*

I really can't understand this. Would someone suggest the right point of view one should adopt when reading this sencence? Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Investors want risk to be compensated, therefore they will only buy more risky assets if the price is right, that is only when they can expect more returns compared to less risky assets.